# Python: AttributeError in dictionary

Tags: python

after executing my code, I got the AttributeError

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'coeffs'
```

What is meant by that and how can I fix this?

I got this error by an automatic grader.
Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Let me guess: you used `.coeffs` instead of `['coeffs']`?

Comment: It means that some variable - which happens to be a `dict`, does not have an attribute named `coeffs`, but such one was looked up. Probably you have something like `d.coeffs` in your code where you really meant `d['coeffs']`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a dictionary object with the key `coeffs`, you then try to access it with

```
your_dict.coeffs
```

This is not how you access a key inside a dict in Python, you do it like this `your_dict['coeffs']`

Comment: Here's the fault. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use 
`your_dict.get('coeffs')`

which lets you specify a "default" value:

`your_dict.get('coeffs', default_value)`

if the key does not exists.

very usefull when you're not sure if the key is already present in the dict.